# MX records for G Suite Gmail:The domain name must have a valid TLD label

Tags: gmail, cpanel

I am adding MX records in cPanel for G Suite Gmail using this link: https://support.google.com/a/answer/140034.  The problem is I can't add the MX record because I get the error:

> The domain name must have a valid TLD label

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you registered and created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Comment: You added a period at the end. Remove it and see if it works.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem and removing the period from the end of the destination (e.g. `ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM` in place of `ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.`) fixed it for me.